# How to group several classes without namespaces in typescript

Tags: typescript

From what I understand, typescript seems to discourage namespaces with ES6 modules, however I seem to have a case where I want to group several classes and be sure of what I'm using and where it is coming from. Although I cannot provide my actual code, I am attaching some minimal examples of what I'm trying to achieve, and want to understand the best practice for such a case.

In my code I have files with similar names under various directories, these files however have different use cases such as interacting with an API or interacting with a database.

My folder structure looks something like the following

```
src/
├── api/
│   └── shape/
│       ├── triangle
│       ├── circle
│       └── square
└── database/
    └── shape/
        ├── tirangle
        ├── circle
        └── square
```

**What I want to achieve**

For this question I'm just focusing on the database directory and I want to be able to access my database code in the following manner.

```
const results = Database.Shape.triangle.methodName();
```

and also have the ability to import the triangle class for example, directly. This would be the case when the consumer file is not using any other triangle.

I want to do this because I want to be sure that it is the database that I'm accessing since I have classes with similar names for other purposes. I could achieve a 2 level nesting according to have typescript has shown in their [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html), however I'm not quite sure how I would do this with another level of nesting.

```
export class Triangle {
  /* ... */
}
export class Square {
  /* ... */
}

---

import * as shapes from "./shapes";
let t = new shapes.Triangle();
```

Just to clarify, I'm in a NodeJS environment.

Comment: Why not use renamed imports ?

Comment: Can you just use ECMAScript modules? All the imports and exports are explicit so you'll know where things came from.

Comment: Re-export the wildcard imports: `export { shapes }`

Comment: @Jimmy it is a design choice which I would like to achieve. I feel it will be more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example file structure

```
src/
├── api/
│   └── shapes/
│       ├── triangle
│       ├── circle
│       └── square
```

Have an `src/api/shape/index.ts` file like this:

```
import Square from "./square";
import Triangle from "./triangle";
import Circle from "./circle";

export default {
    Square, Triangle, Circle
}
```

And then an `src/api/index.ts` file like:

```
import Shapes from "./shapes";

export default {
    Shapes
}
```

And then let's say you have a `src/app.ts` file you can do this:

```
import Api from "./api";

const triangle = Api.Shapes.Triangle.methodName();
```

==Updated==

Original poster in comments said they wanted to have the option to import Triangle directly from `./api`, so here is how you can do that:

src/api/shapes/triangle.ts

```
export class Triangle {
    static someMethod() {}
}
```

src/api/shapes/index.ts

```
export { Square } from "./square";
export { Triangle } from "./triangle";
```

src/api/index.ts

```
import * as Shapes from "./shapes";

export * from './shapes'

export default {
    Shapes
}
```

src/app.ts

```
import Api, { Triangle } from "./api";

const triangle = Api.Shapes.Triangle.someMethod();
const triangle2 = Triangle.someMethod();
```

So you'd have either option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to import just triangle from the "./api" module. I want the explicit chaining on certain files with a lot of code, whereas smaller files could do well with direct access to the class.

Comment: Yes, you can do `import Triangle from "./api/shapes/triangle";`

Comment: I was hoping to be able to import it from `./api` but I suppose, getting it from the full path shouldn't matter. Thanks again!

Comment: You could do that too. Have your individual files like this:
```
export class Triangle {
    static someMethod() {}
}
```

And your `src/api/indexs.ts` like this:

```
import Shapes from "./shapes";

export * from './shapes/triangle'
export * from './shapes/square'

export default {
    Shapes
}
```

And your main file like:

```
import Api, { Triangle } from "./api";

const triangle = Api.Shapes.Triangle.someMethod();
const triangle2 = Triangle.someMethod();
```

So you see you can have either option that way

Comment: See my updated post above